# Got Undefined instead of the text content

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to get the text content corresponding the button I click but received "You selected Undefined out of 5" instead.  Is there anyway that I can get, for example "You selected 5 out of 5" instead of "You selected Undefined out of 5".

```js
const cardContainer = document.querySelector('.card-container')
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit')
const thankYouCard = document.createElement('div')
const ratingButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.rating')
let number;

thankYouCard.innerHTML = `
<div id="annoucement">You selected ${number} out of 5</div>

<header>Thank you!</header>

<main id="thank-you">We appreciate you taking the time to give a rating. If you ever need more support, 
don't hesitate to get in touch! </main>`
ratingButtons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    number = e.target.textContent
    console.log(number);
  })
})

function submit() {
  cardContainer.innerHTML = ''
  cardContainer.appendChild(thankYouCard)
}
submitButton.addEventListener('click', submit)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Interactive rating component</title>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Rating state start -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <header>How did we do?</header>
    <main> Please let us know how we did with your support request. All feedback is appreciated to help us improve our offering!</main>
    <div id="rating-container">
      <button class="rating">1</button>
      <button class="rating">2</button>
      <button class="rating">3</button>
      <button class="rating">4</button>
      <button class="rating">5</button>
    </div>
    <button id="submit">Submit</div> 
  </div>

  <script >
 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you set `thankYouCard.innerHTML` in your code, `number` is indeed `undefined`. It becomes a static string, it’s not dynamically updated afterward with changes to `number`. Set the string in question once `number` is set, maybe as part of the handler on the event listener.

Comment: A template literal doesn't automatically update itself when you reassign the variable. The variable value is substituted when you create it.

Comment: The way to do this is to create a `<span>` to hold the number. Then when the number changes you can assign to the span's `innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the place where you have set the the thankYouCard content.

You have defined number as `let number;`. At that time the value of number is undefined. Then you have defined the content for thankYouCard with `number` variable.

Only when the submit event occurs, we will get the value for `number`. So we should set the content for thankYouCard only after that.

```js
const cardContainer = document.querySelector('.card-container')
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit')
const thankYouCard = document.createElement('div')
const ratingButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.rating')
let number;

ratingButtons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    number = e.target.textContent
    console.log(number);
  })
})

function submit() {
  cardContainer.innerHTML = ''
  thankYouCard.innerHTML = `
    <div id="annoucement">You selected ${number} out of 5</div>

    <header>Thank you!</header>

    <main id="thank-you">We appreciate you taking the time to give a rating. If you ever need more support, don't hesitate to get in touch! </main>`
  cardContainer.appendChild(thankYouCard)
}
submitButton.addEventListener('click', submit)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Interactive rating component</title>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Rating state start -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <header>How did we do?</header>
    <main> Please let us know how we did with your support request. All feedback is appreciated to help us improve our offering!</main>
    <div id="rating-container">
      <button class="rating">1</button>
      <button class="rating">2</button>
      <button class="rating">3</button>
      <button class="rating">4</button>
      <button class="rating">5</button>
    </div>
    <button id="submit">Submit</div> 
  </div>

  <script >
 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```